# In Jupyter, header top margin is too big and changing style has no effect

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using some css/html in a Jupyter notebook to add some flair to the markdown:

Cell 1:

```
Here is the cell before, full of useful things.
```

Cell 2:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <h1>Why am I so far away?</h1>
An info cell, fairly useful things.
</div>
```

It appears like this:

[image: lonely cell]

Following [a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124877/css-styling-of-html-in-ipython-notebook-output), I tried to fix by changing the `h1` style:

```
<style>
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

I did this in a separate markdown cell in the notebook (but also tried it in the same cell), and it had no effect. I also tried the same with the `div` style, but no effect.

**Edit**
ChatGPT just told me I could put try specifying the style inline:

```
<h1 style="margin-top: 0;">Why am I so far away?</h1>
```

This works for now, but I don't like it because it will be a lot of extra typing in my notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The two problems you may have encountered are:

1. `<style>`-tags are removed when the markdown cell is rendered
2. Often there are already some more specific css rules, so your css will be overwritten ([CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity))

### Solution

You will need a code cell to apply the styles (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570738/21597449) and you have to add the `!important` flag to your css rule. In your case this will look like the following:

```html
%%html
<style>
    h1 {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Or

```py
from IPython.display import HTML
styles = """
<style>
    h1 {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
"""
HTML(styles)
```

*tested on JupyterLab 4.0.x*